# Making a check box visible in a report based on a string value in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

First off, i created an Album of screen shots describing my problem **Click [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyL90.jpg)**(4 images hosted on imgur.com)!

Includes a brief description of each image.

(I am new to VB, but i have some programming background)

So as the title suggests i am trying to set the visibility of a `CheckBox` in a REPORT, based on a string value in a query.

I am getting the *RunTime* error shown in the **[Screenshot Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyL90.jpg)**. Ive been trying to google the problem all day with no luck.

I think i might be incorrectly referencing the report `[Reports]![Report_rptTenure_sub]`, but i cant be sure.

Any input or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it might be `[Reports]![rptTenure_sub]`, just based on the actual name shown on the tab of the report in your screenshot.

Comment: Ive tried many different name types. I know that when i am in the visual basics window it adds a "Form_" or a "Reports_" to the start of the name. I feel like it could be used either way.

Ive tried "Reports![rptTenure_sub]![chkLimitedTerm]" which is the string that access created for me through the query builder. No luck.

Comment: does `Reports![rptTenure_sub]![chkLimitedTerm]` give you the same error?

Comment: Correction, you were correct.

Reports![rptTenure_sub]!chkTenured.Visible is the correct way to refrence the report.